# How to deploy with Capistrano, restarting unicorn service without sudo and without a root SSH connection

Tags: ssh, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

I'm new with Capistrano, and after reading documentation I can deploy all app files and `service unicorn reload`, but I think I could do it better.

The documentation says to create a user without password, but I try to avoid this option.

Now I'm using two users, one is `root` with an SSH connection (to reload unicorn), but I have read it is a bad practice, and the another is `rails` default Digitalocean autocreated.

I connect with both via SSH to the server.

In Capistrano files, I have:

production.rb:

```
set :deploy_to, "/home/rails/www/digitalshelving"
role :web, %w{rails@xx.xxx.xxx.xx}
server "xx.xxx.xxx.xx", user: "rails", roles: %w{web}
```

And a .rake file (task):

```
namespace :deploy_ds do
    task :reload_unicorn do
      on "root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx" do
        execute :service, "unicorn reload"
      end
    end

    task :upload_git do
        run_locally do
         # Git add + commit + push
        end
    end
end

before "deploy:starting", "deploy_ds:upload_git"

after "deploy:finished", "deploy_ds:reload_unicorn"
```

I think I should avoid `root` `ssh` connections, but then, I can not execute `service unicorn reload`.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: You can configure the rails user to have passwordless sudo, *only for the unicorn commands*?

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution, I didn't know this was possible, I have found how to do dat here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password/159009#159009

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Tom Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord) I managed to do it giving to the user used for deployment the capacity to execute `sudo service unicorn reload` without password.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password/159009#159009) is explained.

For me, is the best solution in smaller projects with only one developper and Linux administrator, better than creating a user without password as it says [Capistrano docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/).

Now I can deactivate root access with SSH, as is recommended.

Even though any comment or correction will be more accurate and welcome, due to my lack of linux security knowledge